# stored function returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I create the following function on MASTER db so you can replicate it without problems

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[sf_GetDateAggioGAP]
                   (@name varchar,@type_desc VARCHAR)
RETURNS DATETIME AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT DATETIME
    DECLARE @DATA DATETIME
    DECLARE @RIPETI INT 
    SET @DATA = (SELECT DISTINCT create_date as DATINI FROM  sys.all_objects WHERE (name = @name) AND (TYPE_DESC = @type_desc))
    SET @RIPETI = (SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_ID as RIPETI FROM  sys.all_objects WHERE (name = @name) AND (TYPE_DESC = @type_desc))
    SET @RESULT=@DATA
        WHILE @DATA <= getdate()
        BEGIN
        SET @DATA=dateadd(month,@RIPETI,@DATA)
        IF @DATA > GETDATE()
        BREAK
        ELSE
        CONTINUE
        SET @RESULT=@DATA
        END  
        RETURN @RESULT
    END
```

When i call my function in this way `"select dbo.sf_getdateaggiogap('sysrscols','system_table') as datanext from sys.all_objects where name ='sysrscols'"` the result is always null
the code run correctly but the query's result is always null.
where am i wrong?

THANKS

Comment: You had your capslock on

Comment: Not a good start. Writing with `Capslock On` is like shouting

Comment: I'm really sorry. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Missing Size for parameters ....

```
Alter  FUNCTION [dbo].[sf_GetDateAggioGAP]
                   (@name varchar(max),@type_desc VARCHAR(max))
```